# Can I overwrite route attribute of an ASP.NET Core controller with controller route mapping

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Core web app that references a thirdparty dll that contains its own controller.

The controller has the following attributes:

```cs
[NonController]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Area("ThirdPartyArea")]
[Route("[area]/[controller]/[action]")]
public class ThirdPartyController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{scheme?}")]
    public IActionResult ThirdPartyAction([FromRoute] string scheme)
    {
```

It seems I can't overwrite this attribute by a route mapping:

```cs
endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
    name: "ThirdPartyRoute",
    areaName: "ThirdPartyArea",
    pattern: "my/custom/url/prefix/{controller}/{action}");
```

Because accessing the URL lands on a 404 page: https://localhost:44368/my/custom/url/prefix/thirdparty/thirdpartyaction

Does anyone know how I can overwrite the route attribute of this controller so that I can access it with my custom URL prefix?

Comment: Why you don't use Attribute for this action with custom route?

Comment: @DawidWekwejt Because the DLL is a third party dll, I can't change the controller route attribute.

Comment: Hmm, the Route attribute includes the area name in the route. What happens if you change your pattern to "my/custom/url/prefix/thirdparty/{controller}/{action}" and hit `https://localhost:44368/my/custom/url/prefix/thirdparty/thirdparty/thirdpartyaction`

Comment: @phuzi doesn't work unfortunately. In fact I have a link on my home page displaying the path of the third party action: `<a asp-action="ThirdPartyAction" asp-controller="ThirdParty" asp-area="ThirdPartyArea">@Url.Action("ThirdPartyAction", "ThirdParty", new { Area = "ThirdPartyArea" })</a>`. So far regardless my different attempts, it is always `ThirdPartyArea/ThirdParty/ThirdPartyAction`.

Comment: Controller or action attribute route is always has priority. There is no way you can change it without  changing controller or action attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to modify the routing attributes on the controller for access, like the example in the official documentation：

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(name: "duck_route", 
                                     areaName: "Duck",
                                     pattern: "Manage/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default",
                                 pattern: "Manage/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

---

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MyApp.Namespace4
{
    [Area("Duck")]
    public class UsersController : Controller
    {
        // GET /Manage/users/GenerateURLInArea
        public IActionResult GenerateURLInArea()
        {
            // Uses the 'ambient' value of area.
            var url = Url.Action("Index", "Home");
            // Returns /Manage/Home/Index
            return Content(url);
        }

        // GET /Manage/users/GenerateURLOutsideOfArea
        public IActionResult GenerateURLOutsideOfArea()
        {
            // Uses the empty value for area.
            var url = Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" });
            // Returns /Manage
            return Content(url);
        }
    }
}
```

For more operations, please refer to the document：https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#token-replacement-in-route-templates-controller-action-area

Comment: Unfortunate, the controller is in a third party DLL that I'm unable to change. Thanks for the documentation link although they don't really apply to my case here.